# Some of my fonts work, some don't (404 error) Chrome & Aurora

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

I use two fonts which came from the same website, are located in the same directory and are I use the same CSS to load both of them but one of them just won't load from the server. Everything works when I open the website locally. I want to make it clear that I do not host the fonts on a subdomain so my guess it's that it ain't a ACAO problem. Here's the code :

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'OpenSansLight';
src: url('OpenSans-Light-webfont.eot');
src: url('OpenSans-Light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('OpenSans-Light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('OpenSans-Light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('OpenSans-Light-webfont.svg#OpenSansLight') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal; }

@font-face {
font-family: 'OpenSansBold';
src: url('OpenSans-SemiBold-webfont.eot');
src: url('OpenSans-SemiBold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('OpenSans-SemiBold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('OpenSans-SemiBold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('OpenSans-SemiBold-webfont.svg#OpenSansLight') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal; }
```

Only the bold version does not work.

Here's the website for you to see : http://www.kromaentreprises.com/2/

Comment: I answered my own question, the problem was that the name of the files were OpenSans-Semibold-webfont and in the css it was called OpenSans-SemiBold-webfont, all of this for a capital letter ! That css was generated by FontSquirrel so it's their problem. I hope this will help someone :)